# How to disable "-Werror=unused-variable" flag in yocto

Tags: c++, yocto

I am getting following error in yocto :

error: unused variable 'array' [-Werror=unused-variable]

But I want to suppress it. How can I do that in yocto recipe? What exactly I should write in recipe?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26003402/how-to-add-global-cxx-compiler-flag-to-yocto-build#:~:text=You%20can%20add%20it%20to,is%20defined%20in%20your%20local.

Comment: If you have an unused variable, why don't you just remove it?

Answer (score 1):

This was resolved by adding
TARGET_CFLAGS += "-Wno-unused-variable"
in recipe.